# Time series forecasting with NARX in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

I want to use a NARX (Non-linear AutoRegressive Network with eXogenous input) for time series forecasting and I am desperatly searching for the right package and function in R. 
Other answers to the same question in this forum came up with

- `nnetTs()` of the `tsDyn` package or
- `nnetar()` in the `forecast` package. Additionally I found the
- `elm()` function in the `nnfor` package.

But non of them seems equivalent to for example the NARX model in Matlab, which I am trying to avoid.

`nnetTs()` has no argument for exogenous input variables (aka. external regressors) which is essential to the NARX model. `nnetar()` has these external regressors and is autoregressive, but provides no argument to set the lag of the regressors.

Finally the question: Is there any real NARX eqivalent in R?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

`mlp` function of `nnfor` package in R, which is an equivalent to NARX. This function provides external regressors and lags:

> xreg: Exogenous regressors. Each column is a different regressor and
>   the sample size must be at least as long as the target in-sample set,
>   but can be longer.
>
> xreg.lags: This is a list containing the lags for
>   each exogenous variable. Each list is a numeric vector containing
>   lags. If xreg has 3 columns then the xreg.lags list must contain three
>   elements. If NULL then it is automatically specified.

See the [example by Nikolaos Kourentzes](http://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2017/10/25/new-r-package-nnfor-time-series-forecasting-with-neural-networks/) below:

```
library(nnfor)
# The objective is to forecast the Airline Passengers series with only deterministic trend and seasonality
# mlp does the deterministic seasonality internally, when needed, but not the trend.

# Let us prepare some data
y <- AirPassengers
plot(y)
h <- 2*frequency(y)
tt <- cbind(c(1:(length(y)+h),rep(0,2*h)))
plot(tt)
# Observe that the deterministic trend ends with zeros
print(tt)

# Fit a network with no differencing, no univariate lags, and fixed deterministic trend
fit1 <- mlp(y,difforder=0,lags=0,xreg=tt,xreg.lags=list(0),xreg.keep=TRUE)
print(fit1)
plot(fit1)
plot(forecast(fit1,h=h,xreg=tt))
# The forecast is reasonable

# Now let us shift the input so that the zeros are in the forecast period
tt2 <- tt[-(1:h),,drop=FALSE]
plot(forecast(fit1,h=h,xreg=tt2))
# The seasonality is there, but there is zero trend, as the inputs suggest. 
# Also note that the mlp modelled multiplicative seasonality on its own. NNs are cool. 

# Now let us fit a network on the shifted inputs
# I will ask for outplot=1 to see the model fit
fit2 <- mlp(y,difforder=0,lags=0,xreg=tt2,xreg.lags=list(0),xreg.keep=TRUE,outplot=1)
plot(fit2)
plot(forecast(fit2,h=h,xreg=tt2))
# Same as before

# Now lets fit with two inputs, the shifted (lead of 24 periods) and the original trend
fit3 <- mlp(y,difforder=0,lags=0,xreg=cbind(tt[1:192,,drop=FALSE],tt2),xreg.lags=list(0,0),xreg.keep=list(TRUE,TRUE),outplot=1)
print(fit3)
plot(fit3)
plot(forecast(fit3,h=h,xreg=cbind(tt[1:192,,drop=FALSE],tt2)))
# The network gets a bit confused with one of the trend vectors stopping!
```